# Delete ' signs out of multiple cells in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I have got a 2x5 cell-array containing char strings. E.g. it looks like this:

```
{'''ABC''' , '''DEF''' , '''GHI'''   , '''-'''   , '''MNO'''; ...
'''PQR''' , '''STU''' , '''Value''' , '''XYZ''' , '''-'''}
```

So for example, if I give out one cell, the output is following: `''ABC''`. Now I want the output to be `'ABC'`. How can i delete all `'` of the cells?

Comment: Please edit this question to make that an actual Matlab cell array i.e. drop all the `|`s and use the `{}` syntax so we know exactly how your data are stored

Comment: Ok sorry, but done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you just want to loop through each element of the cell array and drop the first and the last character:

```
A = {'''ABC''' , '''DEF''' , '''GHI'''   , '''-'''   , '''MNO''';'''PQR''' , '''STU''' , '''Value''' , '''XYZ''' , '''-'''}

cellfun(@(x)x(2:end-1),A,'uni',0)
```

Comment: Thank you! How bad, I didn't realise this way to solve my problem. Just being a blockhead today.